# Google Sheets Conditional Formating "If cell A1 contains_text AND cell B1 contains_text" highlight A1

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, gs-conditional-formatting

I have a problem with set conditional formatting depends to sum 2 conditions

Spreadsheet column headers A:A Animal, B:B Name C:C Information

I need to highlight A2 if there will be in cells
 A2 Dog  C2 Barking

Basically, it's just a kind of
If A1="Dog" AND B1="Barking" THEN use highlight

Below link to example sheet 
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1E0MiHpNFbIae-zQCTNppqoxrqiD1-v1bWyoLMvq7rYQ/edit?usp=sharing

[image: Sheet View]

EDIT:

Is there a possibility to add OR condition?

So total conditions will be something like this:

```
=AND($A1="Dog"; C1="Barking" OR C1="Scratching")
```

Comment: `=AND($A1="Dog"; OR(C1="Barking"; C1="Scratching"))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for row color:

```
=AND($A1="Dog"; $C1="Barking")
```

[image: 0]

---

for cell color:

```
=AND($A1="Dog"; C1="Barking")
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Probably someone with reputation 15+ should help :( my votes are not counting, also I dont see accept answer button.

Comment: Got only something like this
Upvote (I did already but with my rep it's not counting)
Downvote
And Favourite
https://ibb.co/2ZVH0Gn

Comment: @RobertdeClair that is the area of your question on your screenshot. if you scroll down on the answer you will find the checkmark (near the answer)

Comment: Silly me, Thanks again :)